# Prove that the area of the triangle $AEF$ where the quadrilaterals $ABDE$ and $ABCF$ are parallelograms is $\sqrt{110}$

Tags: geometry, vectors

$ABCD$ is a tetrahedron with position vectors of its angular points as $A(-5,22,5);B(1,2,3);C(4,3,2);D(-1,2,-3)$.Prove that the area of the triangle $AEF$ where the quadrilaterals $ABDE$ and $ABCF$ are parallelograms is $\sqrt{110}$

---

For finding the area of triangle $AEF$,we need to find the coordinates of $E$ and $F$,as the coordinates of $A$ are given.As $A,B,C,D$ is a tetraheron,So $A,B,C,D$ are the points in the space ,not in the plane.

I am not able to find the coordinates.
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Since $ABDE$ is a parallelogram, $\vec{AD}=\vec{AB}+\vec{AE}$. That gives you the coordinates $\vec{AE}$, hence of $E$. However, you can use $\vec{AE}$ and $\vec{AF}$ to get the area of $\triangle AEF$.

Comment: Calculated in this way as suggested by you gives area of triangle $AEF=\sqrt{91}$,not the required answer,sir@QuangHoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have
$$\vec{AE}=\vec{BD}=(-1-1,2-2,-3-3)=(-2,0,-6)$$
and
$$\vec{AF}=\vec{BC}=(4-1,3-2,2-3)=(3,1,-1),$$
the area of the triangle $AEF$ is 
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{|\vec{AE}|^2|\vec{AF}|^2-(\vec{AE}\cdot\vec{AF})^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{40\times 11-0}=\sqrt{110}.$$